# GTM Container not found in Preview mode

Tags: google-tag-manager, debug

I got access to this Google Tag Manager (GTM) account.
Tags and triggers seem to work and appear in Google Analytics reports.

But the preview mode in GTM doesn't allow me to do anything.
You can see that I only have the Universal Analytics container ID but not GTM:

[image]

Comment: Do you actually see your GTM container's code loaded in the DOM when you open your dev tools on the Elements tab?

Comment: Hi! no i don't see it in the DOM from the dev tools. This is the link to their site https://bit.ly/3n7eteg

Comment: yep, there's no GTM installed. No wonder you can't use preview properly. To use GTM, one must first install it.

Comment: @BNazaruk, thank you so much for taking the time to look at this. My brain blanked out I guess!